# MessageBodyMember or MessageHeader attribute to encrypt field during serialization

Tags: .net, wcf, serialization

I came across below question for the 70-513 WCF certification exam:

> You develop a Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) SOAP service that contains a
>   class named `Order`. The `Order` class includes a field named `secret` that stores private data. The `Order` class includes the following code:
>
> The service has the following requirements:
>
> The `secret` field must be encrypted. All other fields in the `Order` class must serialize as plain text. You need to configure serialization for the `Order` class. What should you do?
>
> - A. Add a MessageHeader attribute to the secret field and set the ProtectionLevel to Sign.
>     Add a MessageBodyMember attribute to each of the other fields of the class.
> - B. Add a MessageBodyMember attribute to the secret field and set the ProtectionLevel to
>     Sign.
>     Add a MessageBodyMember attribute to each of the other fields of the class.
> - C. Add a MessageBodyMember attribute to the secret field and set the ProtectionLevel to
>     EncryptAndSign.
>     Add a MessageBodyMember attribute to each of the other fields of the class.
> - D. Add a MessageHeader attribute to the secret field and set the ProtectionLevel to
>     EncryptAndSign.
>     Add a MessageBodyMember attribute to each of the other fields of the class.

The answer should be C, but I found someone on the internet saying the answer should be D. Please help.

Comment: Please link to where it is claimed `D` is the correct answer. Please explain what specific part you don't understand. See [WCF messageheader vs messagebodymember?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618869/wcf-messageheader-vs-messagebodymember) for example.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But in the question no where it is mentioned that secret should be header field.so why should MessageHeader attribute should be applied to the secret field.

Comment: I'm asking you for a link that claims `D` is the correct answer. If you can't find it, ignore it, because it is `C`.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it's D. Since soap body can only have one protection level, which means use the highest secure one. So if it's C, all body member will be signed. 
D meets the requirements.